# Shouldn't fmap (+3) (*3) be equivalent to \x -> ((x+3)*3)?

Tags: haskell, functor

In *[Learn you a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids)*, it is given that

```
fmap (+3) (*3)
```

is equivalent to

```
\x -> ((x*3)+3))
```

However, I can't understand why. Isn't it supposed to be `\x -> ((x+3)*3)`?

I don't know the implementation of `fmap` for `(*3)` functor, but my intuition tells me that since the functor `(*3)` is equivalent to `\x -> x * 3`, the map `(+3)` would be first applied and then `(*3)` be applied, but it is the other way around. What am I missing in here?

Comment: `fmap g f` is equivalent `g . f`; therefore, `fmap (+3) (*3)` is equivalent to `(+3) . (*3)`, which amounts to `\x -> (x*3)+3`.

Comment: If `g :: A -> B`, what type do you believe `fmap` has in the expression `fmap undefined g`?

Comment: And as an aside that is not about gathering information that makes it possible to write a better answer: looking up the implementation of something that's behaving differently than you expect is, like, the barest minimum of work that you should be doing before you ask a question here. While learning, confusion is right and proper. But making no effort to approach that confusion on your own isn't.

Comment: @DanielWagner what you are saying is not accurate; see my comment on your answer!

Comment: [Here is the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-982) `fmap = (.)` (and it took me some time and knowledge to find, instances aren't always easy to locate or interpret and Hackage is not a great help -- I would appreciate if we could be more supportive, recognizing how experience we take for granted might not be obvious to someone else @DanielWagner).

Comment: @luqui even that naked code you've provided the link to, is not at all obvious to a newbie. Hackage is a pain for new learners. it is not help, period (pun intended). nor is it docs.

Answer (score 3):

> my intuition tells me that since the functor (*3) is equivalent to `\x -> x * 3`

Functions form a functor instance

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where ...
```

Those are the functions mapping from `r`.

Given a function `g :: r -> a` you can form a new function `h :: r -> b` with the help of `f :: a -> b` via `h = fmap f g`. It should now be clear that `f :: a -> b` cannot be applied first but must be applied second. That is `h' = (g :: r -> a) . (f :: a -> b)` does not make any sense but `h = (f :: a -> b) . (g :: r -> a)` does.

Answer (score 3):

`fmap` has to obey two laws:

1. `fmap id == id`
2. `fmap (f . g) == fmap f . fmap g`

Your proposed definition, `fmap' f g == g . f`, satisfies the first law but violates the second law:

```
fmap' id f == f . id == f == id f  -- OK

fmap' (f . g) h == h . (f . g)
                == (h . f) . g
                == (fmap' f h) . g
                == fmap' g (fmap' f h)
                == (fmap' g . fmap' f) h  -- violation, since (.) is not commutative
```

The correct definition, `fmap f g = f . h`, satisfies both:

```
fmap id f == id . f == f == id f

fmap (f . g) h == (f . g) . h
               == f . (g . h)
               == fmap f (g . h)
               == fmap f (fmap g h)
               == (fmap f . fmap g) h
```

Comment: Isn't the problem more so that it isn't type-correct than that it isn't lawful?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Good point, though in this special case the law fails even when the specific call type checks.

Answer (score 2):

A "functor", in Haskell, is a higher order type, `F`, -- "higher order" meaning, it accepts another type variable, `a` (denoting *any* type whatever), -- such that we can have

```
  F     a                      fa
       (a -> b)                 ab
-----------------
  F          b                 fmap ab fa
```

which is known as "`flip fmap`" (`flip` just means that the order of arguments is flipped, `flip fmap fa ab == fmap ab fa`). There are also some "common sense" laws it must follow.

For `F ~ Maybe`, say, it means

```
flip fmap :: Maybe a ->
                  (a    -> b) ->
             Maybe         b
```

and for `F ~ []`,

```
flip fmap :: []    a ->
                  (a    -> b) ->
             []            b
```

which is more conventionally written as `[a] -> (a -> b) -> [b]`.

In our case here, `F a ~ r -> a`, or more formally, `F a ~ ((->) r) a`, which means `F ~ ((->) r)`,

```
flip fmap :: ((->) r) a ->
                     (a    -> b) ->
             ((->) r)         b
```

which is more conventionally written as `(r -> a) -> (a -> b) -> (r -> b)`,

```
  r -> a
       a -> b
 -------------
  r ->      b
```

which is the same as `(r -> a) -> (a -> b) -> r -> b` since with types, the arrows associate on the right, corresponding to the fact that applications associate on the left: `f a b c` is actually `((f a) b) c` and

```
f    a    b    c =  d          --     f  a  b  c
f    a    b = \c -> d          --    (f  a  b) c
f    a = \b    c -> d          --   ((f  a) b) c
f = \a    b    c -> d          --  (((f) a) b) c
```

are all different ways to write down the same definition, and different ways to write down the same function call.

This then means we need to implement

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
fmap    ab           ra          r =  b
   where
   b =
```

So what could the definition be? Is it up to us to decode what goes where? Well, we must produce a `b` type value. The only thing we have that can do it for us, is `ab :: a -> b`.

Can we produce a `b` without it? Out of the blue? Except for erroring out, no, we can't -- we know *nothing* about that `b` type. It can be *anything*. So we're left with

```
   b = ab a
   a =
```

and now we must get an `a` somewhere, to use it as an argument to `ab`. Fortunately, `ra` can give it to us:

```
   a = ra r
```

and `r`, we already got! So the types did write this implementation for us:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
fmap    ab           ra          r =  b
   where
   b = ab a
   a = ra r
```

or, simplifying and renaming, we get

```
fmap f g r = f  ( g  r)
           = (f . g) r
```

by definition of the function composition, `.`, as

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
(f . g) r = f (g r)
```

which is a valid syntax definition, otherwise written as

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
(.) f g r = f (g r)
```

or

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
(.) f g = \ r -> f (g r)
```

or

```
(.) :: (a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
(.) = \f g r -> f (g r)
```

All these are equivalent. And its type diagram

```
         a -> b
    r -> a
   --------------
    r ->      b
```

As for the intuition, a functorial type value of type `F A` is, loosely, an `F`-type "something" than can somehow *produce* an `A`-type something, in some `F`-type sense.

The functor *laws* mean that `F` does so in some purely "structural", mechanical way, without regard to what that `A` value that it produces actually is. In other words, the `A` values do not influence how they are produced, only the `F` type itself determines that.

For example, `Maybe Int` could `Maybe` produce an `Int`. Or `[Int]` could produce several `Int`s. `(*3)` can also produce an `Int`, if we supply it with an `Int` argument.

What then this `fmap` is? What does it do? It *transforms* that would-be produced *value*. Every functor type must define its `fmap`, that is what makes it *be* a functorial type, that it defines the

```
instance Functor Maybe where
  fmap ab (Just a) = (Just (ab a))
```

etc. So then, with functions `r -> a`, which produce that `a` type value promised by their type, after being applied to an argument, we transform that value by applying the transformation function to it:

```
 fmap transf mult3 arg = tansf (mult3 arg)
```

which is just the definition of the functional composition itself, with arguments renamed.

So that's why, in this case,

```
 fmap (+3) (*3) r = (+3) ((*3) r)
                  = (+3) (r*3)
                  =      (r*3) + 3
```

we `(+3)` transform the value produced by `(*3)` in the *`((->) r)`* sense, which is *application* to some user-supplied argument, `r`. So `(*3)` must be applied first, to get (it to produce) that value.