# Writing a function in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types

I want to write a function for the co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c. Can someone please provide a clear and simple explanation on how to write a Haskell function for co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

I am working thru the chapter 5 exercises (given the type, write the function) in the Haskell programming from first principles, the question reads:

Only one version will type check:

```
co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
co = undefined
```

I am not sure how to start this problem

Comment: Do you understand the function signature? Suppose someone gives you a function with this signature. Could you use it?

Comment: Did you mean `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`?

Comment: I am working thru the chapter 5 exercises (given the type, write the function) in the Haskell programming from first principles, the question reads: 

Only one version will type check:
co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
co = undefined

Comment: I understand the function signature but not sure how I would approach a solution just yet

Comment: @nlkonneh: The type signature, reading left to right is this. I take a function (input type b, output type c). I take a function (input type a, output type b). The whole thing goes from type a to type c. This is function composition, right? If you do this in the GHCi REPL, you get the same signature `:t (.)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I just finishing up types (Haskell programming from first principles) and it was kinda trippy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure how to start this problem

This is how:

```
co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c 
co       = undefined
co f     = undefined  -- f ::      b -> c    co f :: (a -> b) -> a -> c 
co f g   = undefined  -- g :: a -> b         co f g ::           a -> c
co f g a = c          -- a :: a              co f g a ::              c
  where               -- c ::           c
  c = undefined
```

So that's the few first steps we can make. Now,
what can produce a `c` for us? The `f` can:

```
  c = f b             -- f ::      b -> c
  b = undefined
```

And that's another step. But now we need a `b`.
What can produce a `b` for us? The `g` can:

```
  b = g a             -- g :: a -> b
```

And can we get an `a` somewhere? Do we need to?

See also: [Defining a function that satisfies a type in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71759825/defining-a-function-that-satisfies-a-type-in-haskell)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It makes sense when broken down like this 

Comment: [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338264/849891).